# ECS agent can't pull private docker image, despite having the correct ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_* values in ecs.config

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

I'm using AWS Batch to run code from a private Docker image.

I followed the blog tutorial from this page: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/how-to-authenticate-private-container-registries-using-aws-batch/

To connect to a private Docker registry, I use a user-data script that connects to Docker Hub and successfully authenticate. I do so on an ECS Optimized EC2 instance.

An access to my running EC2 instance (when the job is launched) shows me I have a `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` file with the following included:

```
ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_TYPE=dockercfg
ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_DATA={"registry-1.docker.io":{"auth":"aHRh...wxyz"}}
```

Given AWS documentation, this should be enough for an ECS optimized EC2 instance to connect to private Docker registry and pull the image: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth-container-instances.html

But I get the following error:

```
Unable to find image 'registry-1.docker.io/username/private-image:0.1.0' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for registry-1.docker.io/username/private-image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
```

I made a test of copying the content of `/root/.docker/config.json` (that I used to fill `ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_DATA` value) into `~/.docker/config.json`, and then the `docker pull` worked.

This made me conclude that ECS variables are not well loaded when the instance starts.

Any idea on what's wrong or missing? Thanks